# Issue with enrolling student in online course application

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am making an application in Laravel for online courses. I am getting this error when enrolling a user to the course.

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'course_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `course_user` (`course_id`, `user_id`) values (?, 2))
```

This is my route

```
Route::post('/subscription/{course_id}', 'SubscriptionsController@enrolle')->name('enrolle');
```

Subscription controller

```
public function enrolle(Course $course)
{
    auth()->user()->courses()->attach($course);

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Blade form

```
<form method="post" action="/subscription/{{$courses->id}}">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <input type="submit" class="site-btn buy-btn" value="Enroll" >
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're Route Parameter is wrong it must be `course`. The Route Parameter and the Controller Parameter must have the same name.

```
Route::post('/subscription/{course}', 'SubscriptionsController@enrolle')->name('enrolle');
```

Comment: Also his `enrolle` method should be just `enrolle($course)` since only the *id* is passed from the route and not the whole *Course* model.

Comment: @kopz No because Laravel provides [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-model-binding), so you can pass an ID and get the whole model inside the Controller without using an extra `find`

Comment: I was not aware. Good to know.